# On the intuition in a step on this proof of differentiation on $\Bbb{R}^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm reading Protter/Morrey's: *Intermediate calculus*, here:

> [image]
>
> [image]

I don't get what is the intuition for writing it as in $(3)$. Suppose you want to prove that by yourself, writing it that way should come for some reason, you might be able to reproduce the proof by yourself only *feeling* what is needed. I don't have this feeling despite looking at this for some time.

Comment: One even uses this in the proof that shows if a sequence converges, it is Cauchy. You connect two things whose relationship you don't know anything about by including extra things between them where you know something about each individual link.

Comment: The first expression in brackets holds the x coordinate constant; the second expression in brackets holds the y coordinate constant. Can you see why this is useful? (Granted, the textbook author could have pointed this out explicitly.)

Answer (score 1):

Adding and subtracting the same thing is a common enough trick. It's used, for instance, when proving the product rule for differentiation, proving that congruence relations in modular arithmetic are equivalence relations (specifically transitivity), or just about anything that uses the triangle inequality.

Here it is used to take a simultaneous change in two variables and study it as two separate changes, each in one variable. This, in turn, is exactly what lets you use theorem 1 twice to fulfill the proof.

Comment: What is odd is that that taking the triple of values as vectors, we have:

$$(x,y,F(x,y))$$

If we perform arithmetic on it, we have:

$$(x + h, y + k, F[x + h, y + k]) - (x + h, y, F[x + h, y]) + (x, y + k,
   F[x, y + k]) - (x, y, F[x, y])$$

Which yields:


$$(0,2 k,F(h+x,k+y)-F(h+x,y)+F(x,k+y)-F(x,y))$$

But it doesn't seems viable that:

$$(0,2 k,F(h+x,k+y)-F(h+x,y)+F(x,k+y)-F(x,y))=(0,2k,F(0,2k))$$

Perhaps they could be after some limit taking, but it seems confusing.

Comment: The whole thing seems to suggest that:

$$(x+h,y+k,F(x+h,y+k))-(x,y,F(x,y))=(h,k,F(h,k))$$

But I've tried some examples and it failed. I don't know they are meant to be similar with some limit computation - as I said earlier. So how are they equal?